# Preloading a MySQL db connection in R using .Rprofile

Tags: mysql, r, connection

I am new to R and am currently tackling some automation using .Rprofile. I have searched and searched for the correct way of going about this, but have found little information that speaks specifically to the difficulty I am encountering. Please forgive me if this is a naive question, I swear I am trying to get there!

I am setting up a Project in RStudio. It will necessitate interaction with a MySQL db hosted on my computer. Rather than re-entering all of the connection information each time I start up the project, I was attempting to automate the process by utilizing a Project-specific (in the root directory of the project) .Rprofile.

Keying the following into R works perfectly fine:

```
dbxxx <- dbConnect(MySQL(), 
  user='xxx', 
  password='xxx', 
  dbname='dbxxx', 
  host='localhost', 
  unix.sock='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock')
```

R connects to the db and `dbxxx` shows up in my Global Environment pane as a `Formal class MySQLConnection`.

I then tried to do the same thing in the .First section of my Project-specific .Rprofile file, as follows:

```
## Connect to database
cat("\nConnecting to localhost: xxx... ", sep="")
dbxxx <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
    user='xxx', 
    password='xxx', 
    dbname='dbxxx', 
    host='localhost',
    unix.sock='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock')
cat("Connected.\n", sep="")
```

No luck. No connection, and no object is created. I understand that the syntax for .Rprofile is not always the same as that for the R prompt, but for the life of me I can't figure out a fix. At this point, I'm even wondering if this is a good idea or if there might be some way of which I am unaware to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good reasons to avoid using an R configuration file. The most important argument against using it is the portability.

Nonetheless here is how to set it up correctly:

It is important to know the location of the `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` set-up files that are being used.

R only uses one `.Rprofile` and one `.Renviron` in any session: if you have a `.Rprofile` file in your current project, R will ignore `.Rprofile` in `R_HOME` and `HOME`. Likewise, `.Rprofile` in `HOME` overrides `.Rprofile` in `R_HOME`. The same applies to `.Renviron`: you should remember that adding project specific environment variables with `.Renviron` will de-activate other `.Renviron files`.

So try putting your .Rprofile inside your project's folder.

To create a project-specific start-up script, simply create a .Rprofile file in the project’s root directory and start adding R code, e.g. via file.edit(".Rprofile"). Remember that this will make .Rprofile in the home directory be ignored.

Have a look at this [link](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#rprofile) for a complete explanation.

**Option 2:**

Let me suggest you a different approach. Rather than save the whole connection in the .Rprofile, just save user details as follow:

```
/* .Rprofile*/
mysql.user <- list(user='xxx', 
           password='xxx', 
           dbname='dbxxx', 
           host='localhost', 
           unix.sock='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock')
```

Reload Rstudio and try in console:

```
db <- dbConnect(MySQL(),mysql.user)
```

Comment: I understand the portability argument - this is largely for my own learning purposes. I do have the .Rprofile file in the project's root directory. Given this, should my code indeed be working? If so, I am stumped.

Comment: let's go back to basic add `print("This is the Rprofile inside the foo project!")` to your local .Rprofile and reboot RStudio. Let me know if prints this message in console

Comment: also tell me what `getwd()` returns - it should be the same folder as where your rstudio project is

Comment: The `print` function works just fine once added to the .Rprofile in the project directory. `getwd()` returns the correct working directory - one of the first things I did was add a `setwd()` function to the top of the .First section to ensure I was in the right spot.

Comment: All of the correct libraries are being loaded by the `.Rprofile` file, and all of the outputs are being displayed in R before the prompt. The only thing that isn't working is that connection to the MySQL database - something that does work if I type it in by hand, exactly as I have it in the `.Rprofile` file.

Comment: type `dbxxx` in console - what does return? an error?

Comment: add `foo <- 1` does it get created?

Comment: have a look at an alternative option I just posted above

Comment: Sure, I could load some shortcuts into .Rprofile, but that's not really the issue is it? Do you know if it is possible to preload a MySQL database, or am I going to have to type in the connection (in whatever shortened form) each time? That is what I'm asking, I guess.

Comment: 1. Type `dbxxx`, returns: `Error: object dbxxx not found`.

Comment: 2. `foo` does **not** get created when adding it to the end of the .First section!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to have been a relatively easy fix. My immense thanks to @Altons for the patient troubleshooting!

I was enclosing the dbConnect commands *within* the `.First` section. Once I pulled them out of there, everything worked perfectly!

Example of unworking code:

```
.First <- function() {
    dbxxx <- dbConnect(MySQL(), &c)
}
```

Now working code:

```
dbxxx <- dbConnect(MySQL(), &c)
.First <- function() { }
```

where '&c' is the rest of the `dbConnect` function.

Learning is fun!

Comment: glad you find a solution!